# Denormalizing data for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a PostgreSQL database. There are 72 tables in the database. The total number of columns is greater than **1600**. And I would like to index all this data into Elasticsearch and be able to run bool queries over it.

What is the best way to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html) my DB data? 
What tool could be used to join and index all data from the PostgreSQL?

I find it problematic to join data on the PostgreSQL side due to the [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query): columns per table and raw size. 
Also I tried [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/), but there is a performance problem: [Join all PostgreSQL tables and make a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498948/join-all-postgresql-tables-and-make-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logstash jdbc input and elasticsearch output to synchronize the data: https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

Comment: Do you mean to join all tables (over 250 columns in total) on the PostgreSQL side? If yes, there is a limit for a total number of columns per table in PostgreSQL, and in my case, I reach it.